# Proof of the image of a function

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-writing

I need to find $f ((0, 2))$ for $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f (x) = x^2 − 2x$.
Upon drawing the graph I think that the image is [-1,0). Is that right if so how would I prove it. Would the sketch of the graph be enough? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Find the min and max values of $f$ on $[0,2]$ then use the continuity to prove the wanted image is $[min, max]$. From here it's easy to find $f(0, 2)$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=(x-1)^2-1=g(u)=u^2-1,$$
if we set $u=x-1$ and $u\in(-1,1)$. Now $g$ is an *even* function, so $g((-1,1))=g([0,1))$. On the interval $[0,+\infty)$, $g$ is a continuous increasing function, so that, by the *Intermediate Value theorem*, 
$$f((o,2))=g([0,1))=[g(0),g(1))=[-1,0).$$